# Chart.js Bar-Chart Overlaps when screen size too small

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

Good day first, I have this problem when the screen width is too low that the bar chart overlaps. I suspect that it is due to maintainAspectRatio. But since I set this propertie to false because I didn't want the charts to render too small. I only wanted them to shrink in width and not in both axes. Additionally, I controlled the gap between each bar with a white border because I couldn't find another way to solve the problem.

Heres a screen of what i mean:

[image]

And heres how it looks when the screen size is larger:

[image]

Now I have the question, if it is possible to prevent this problem from occurring anyway.

I can provide some code if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by adding `min-width` and `overflow-y` to the card content container.